# Running a Scala app as a Java app

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run the following rocket launching application:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

directly from java like this:

```
java -cp scala-library.jar HelloWorld
```

(obviously after compliling with scala)

but get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
(...)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld.  Program will exit.
```

Have I overseen anything trivial that I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29, I expect scala sets up correct class paths, that is missing from using java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> The default class path is the current
>   directory. Setting the `CLASSPATH`
>   variable or using the `-classpath`
>   command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the
>   current directory in the search path,
>   you must include "." in the new
>   settings.

Adding `.:` (or `.;` on Windows) to the beginning of your classpath should work.

Comment: Thank you, I was certain it was something trivial. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

> java -cp
>   %SCALA_HOME%\lib\scala-library.jar;.
>   HelloWorld

Comment: Are you sure OP's using Windows?